# ServiceStack 3 service not able to be called

Tags: c#, api, servicestack-bsd

I'm working on a legacy ServiceStack application, and I'm trying to add a new endpoint.  It's a servicestack 3 application.  I created new Response, Request, and Service classes for it, like I've done countless times for other endpoints, but for some reason I can't seem to call it.

I even tried just copying previously existing files and rewriting them to fit my needs, but that didn't work either.

Here's my request:

```
    [Route("/OSTicket/UpdateList", "POST")]
    public class OSTicketUpdateListByDBIDRequest
    {
        public int DatabaseID { get; set; }
    }
```

Here's my response:

```
public class OSTicketUpdateListResponse : IHasResponseStatus
{
    public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; }
}
```

And here's my service endpoint:

```
    public OSTicketUpdateListResponse Post(OSTicketUpdateListByDBIDRequest request)
    {

        OSTicketUpdateListResponse response = new OSTicketUpdateListResponse();
        response.ResponseStatus = new ResponseStatus();
        response.ResponseStatus.ErrorCode = "200";

        return response;
    }
```

Do I need to register these files somewhere?  I don't remember having to do that in the past, but it's very possible that I'm missing something.  Whenever I POST to the application using DHC, I get a `404`.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  In my service declaration:

```
public class OSTicketService
```

I forgot to inherit `Service`.